# Is it possible to prevent a Spring Boot app from attempting to connect to IBM MQ?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have a spring boot application that is connecting to an IBM MessageQueue service using the IBM Spring Boot starter:

```
com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter:2.1.2
```

I have a component class listening to the queues and it has the following annotation to enable/disable connecting to the queue:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "queue.enabled", havingValue = "true")
```

I also have the following property in my application.properties:

```
queue.enabled=false
```

This annotation worked for disabling the queue connections when I was connecting to ActiveMQ, but upon changing the codebase to connect to IBM MQ it seems that the connection is unaffected by the ConditionalOnProperty and always tries to connect.

Is there a way to enable/disable connecting to the IBM MQ service upon server startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MQAutoConfiguration class that exists in the *mq-jms-spring-boot-starter* dependency is what is causing the attempted queue connection.

You have two options to fix this issue, one requires you to set a specific property, and the other allows you to define the property you want used to enable or disable the queue connection.

**Option 1**

Set the value `spring.jta.enabled = false` in your *application.properties* file.
(This may not be a preferred option if you're using transactions in your application.)

Looking at the MQAutoConfiguration class, you can see it is conditional on the property `spring.jta.enabled`. Setting that property to false in your *application.properties* file will prevent the MQAutoConfiguration class from being registered, which means no MQ beans get registered, and therefore no attempts will be made to connect to a queue.

**Option 2 (if you don't want to disable JTA)**

Create the package `com.ibm.mq.spring.boot` and create a copy of the *MQAutoConfiguration* class there. Modify the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation to the property of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

Just exclude configuration in your `application.properties`.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=com.ibm.mq.spring.boot.MQAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Perfectly works if I have to use conditionally use different Message Brokers